# html5 spinning ball

Tags: html, html5-animation, spinning

Looking to see an HTML5 example of a ball spinning outward in a circular motion; an example would be like a roulette ball which starts in the middle of a circle, slowly spinning around till it stops (within a number).

Any help or pointers for getting the spinning of a ball in a circular motion down is appreciated!

Comment: Where have you been playing roulette? The ball doesn't start in the middle.. it runs around the outside edge and falls down into the numbered slots as it slows down.

Comment: lol, agreed - was really just trying to articulate what I'm looking for... startig in the middle or running on the edge (and falling in a number) is still the problem I'm looking to solve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xpbAv/5/

Comment: All I see if the '@' symbol - it doesn't rotate or transform?

Comment: The original link would only work in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.), I've updated it to also work in Firefox. If you want IE support you'd need to use the canvas I think.